# Stop Laravel adding back-ticks to decimals in SQL

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm trying to run a select query in Laravel that contains a few decimals.

https://gist.github.com/dynamiccarrots/b16a4779df28a83dbde3479fa31f7a52

For some reason when this runs it gets outputted as the following with back-ticks around the point in the numbers.

https://gist.github.com/dynamiccarrots/9b9a045e562f3bcf825decbd39398126

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like many things with the builder it is expecting a column name for `addSelect`. If you want to add something that isn't a column (which is why the backticking) you might need to get into 'raw' expressions.

I would look into `DB::raw()` or maybe a `selectRaw` call.

Assuming it is seeing a decimal in a column name and assuming that is `table.column` or `db.table.column` and backticking around the decimal points.

Ref:

[Docs (5.5) - Query Builder - Selects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#selects)

[Docs (5.5) - Query Builder - Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#raw-expressions)